# Spring Security fails on WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring-Web-App that fails when I try to deploy it to my local tomcat since I've added Spring-security.

I used the securty-web-auth with a preauth filter. The RolesRetriever fails with fallowing Error-Message

```
class path resource [WEB-INF/web.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

But the web.xml exists and worked before the security setup.

```
<bean id="j2eeMappableRolesRetriever"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever">
    <property name="resourceLoader" ref="webAppContext" />
</bean>

<bean id="webAppContext"
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext" />
```

Has someone and idea, why it fails? It must be within the WebAppContext-Bean but I have no Idea where to set the right path to web.xml

Comment: Double check that the web.xml is in WEB-INF directory really deployed in Tomcat. Make sure that the casing is correct.

Comment: I've checked both of that. Both is correct. WEB-INF/web.xml and it's there